# asp.net mvc3 c# checkbox with NO binding to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, checkbox

I`m using these checkboxes in my view:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="reglist" id="prueba2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="reglist" id="prueba3" />
```

I`m using entity framework and My viewModel table does not contain values for those checkbox.

I need to get the checkbox checked in the controller and keep the ones that were checked previously along requests without binding the chexboxes to classes.

Answer (score 1):

Just so that we're speaking the same language, I typically refer to the things that I save in the database as the "model" and what I use as the model on the view as the "view model".

In that, I would have a model as such:

```
public class Person{
   // properties
}
```

And then I would have a **view model** like so:

```
public class PersonViewModel{
   public Person Person { get; set; }
   public bool OtherNeededValue1 {get; set;}
   public bool OtherNeededValue2 {get; set;}
}
```

Now, on your view, user PersonViewModel as the model. Then, in your controller, your action will look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create (PersonViewModel viewModel)
{
     if (viewModel.OtherNeededValue1)
     {
         // do something
     }

     var p = new Person { 
                          FirstName = viewModel.Person.FirstName 
                        };

}
```

This way you don't cloud your model with unnecessary properties, but you can still take advantage of the rich binding of MVC.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an AJAX call to your controller every time a checkbox is clicked.

**Ajax Call**

```
    $(function () {
        $(':checkbox').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CheckBoxStatus")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { isChecked: $(this).is(':checked'),
                        id: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function (result) { }
            });
        });
    });
```

this will send the status and the value of the checkbox to the controller and the you can store the info in whatever way like.

**Controller Method**

```
public void CheckBoxStatus(bool isChecked, int id)
{
   // Do what you like here 
}
```